# Heuristic function

Tags: search-algorithms, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

Is there any way to prove that an admissible heuristic may not be consistent?
Most proof I came across are through examples .Is there a generalized proof?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Do you have a specific instance of the problem that you weren't sure how to handle?  One valid way to dis-prove "X is always true" is to exhibit one example where X isn't true, so it's not clear what you are asking -- it seems you already know of some counterexamples, so I can't tell what you are looking for.

Comment: A counterexample *is* a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prove a heuristic is not consistent a counterexample is all you need, you don't need a more "generalized" proof. A counterexample is proof enough.

This is because a heuristic is consistent if some property *always* holds. It is not consistent if the property doesn't hold *once*. An example is all you need to show something happens *once*, if you want to show something *always* holds then you need a general proof.

Comment: can you provide a counterexample .

Comment: "if you want to show something always holds then you need a general proof."Liked this line.Thanks.

Comment: @Alex_ban $2$ is a counterexample to the claim "all even numbers are squares".